# Why does the page reload after sending a POST request?

Tags: javascript, json, forms, fetch, json-server

Why does the page reload after sending a POST request to the json-server-auth (local database)? How to solve this problem? Due to the reboot, I don't have time to get the data and record it.

```
<form class="form">
        <input type="email">
        <input type="password">
        <button>Регистрация</button>
</form>
```

```
<code lang="javascript">

const form = document.querySelector('.form')

form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()

   let data = {
      email: e.target[0].value,
      password: e.target[1].value
    }
    
    let res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/signup', {
       method: "POST",
       headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
     })
     let json = await res.json()
     console.log(json)
     return false
})
```

```
I tried the same code in codepen and there is no reboot, but when sending from the browser via Live Server in VS Code, the page is reloaded.
```

Comment: Are you adding the JavaScript correctly? Because you're using a code tag here and it seems to work when I run it, apart from the failed fetch

Comment: Also the return false is unnecessary since you're already using preventDefault and since it's wrapped in a promise because of the async, the false won't be recognised

Answer (score 0):

As @Nico already mentioned: if you replace your "code"-tag with `<script>` it will work:

```html
<body>
<form class="form">
    <input type="email">
    <input type="password">
    <button>Регистрация</button>
</form>
</body>
<script>

const form = document.querySelector('.form')

form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()

   let data = {
  email: e.target[0].value,
  password: e.target[1].value
}
// I replaced your sign-up-URL with a publicly available API for testing:
let res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
 })
 let json = await res.json()
 console.log(json)
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found reason. It was Live Server VS Code. When i send request in my local bd.json, live server reload my page. I added db.json in ignor, and now it work)